# Como subir meu projeto Node.js para o Heroku?

Tags: node.js, deploy, heroku

Tenho [um projeto](http://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/blinky_lights/) que usa Node.js, Websockets, Socket.io e HTML5 rodando em minha rede wireless interna. Quero colocá-lo público usando o Heroku.

Por favor, digam-me os passos a serem seguidos para que eu atinja o meu objetivo.

Answer (score 3):

1. Abra uma conta no [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

   1. É windows? [Instale o Heroku Toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#local-workstation-setup)
2. Faça o login, digitando `heroku login` na shell
3. Crie o projeto, digitando `heroku create` na shell
4. Se não existir, crie um `Procfile` na raiz do projeto com o seguinte:

   ```
   web: node app.js
   ```
5. Faça o deploy, digitando `git push heroku master` na shell

Dúvidas? Mais detalhes? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: ė linux

Preciso também tirar o SSL do projeto do googlecreative

Answer (score 2):

Além do que o Cigano citou, você antes de outras configurações terá que ativar o websockets na sua aplicação, pois ainda é experimental no Heroku:

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
```

Tem mais aqui:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Entre 4 e 5, se ainda não fez, você tem que ter um repositório git no seu projeto, com um remote adicionado:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:seu-app-name.git
```

Siga os passos, se tiver algum problema ou dúvida mais pontual, exponha para nós.

Comment: Por favo: tendo o heroku não vou precisa de dynamin Dns (dyndns) no raspberry pi ? Nem de instalar ddclient no raspberry pi ?