# Subindo aplicação Ruby on Rails no Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Segui completamente o que estava escrito nesse [tutorial](http://www.rodrigoaguas.com/blog/deploy-de-aplicacao-ruby-on-rails-no-heroku/) e obtive este erro:

```
root@neuber-HP-EliteBook-8460p:/home/neuber/node-js-sample/franca# git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 60, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 14.00 KiB, done.
Total 60 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/NoLockfile
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:loveforme.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:loveforme.git
```

Não gerei arquivo de *log*.

Fiz o que o Cigano pediu e sai erro:

```
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundli
```

Instalei o SQLite3 1.X.X e agora deu o erro derradeiro:

```
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:loveforneuber.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:loveforneuber.gi
```

Estou tentando subir uma aplicaçao simples em Node que já rodou no shelll do Node, mas quando comando Heroku `create` (antes do deploy) dá aquela tela azul de erro de aplicativo no browser.

Answer (score 2):

O erro é claro.

> Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.

Antes de fazer o push novamente, execute:

```
bundle install
```

No caso do segundo erro apontado, primeiro execute este comando:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'
```

Depois volte a executar o `bundle install`.

---

Sobre o erro relacionado ao SQLite, o Heroku não suporta SQLite [com bons motivos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3). Modifique seu arquivo `Gemfile` para utilizar SQLite apenas em desenvolvimento. Ou seja, verifique se a declaração da `gem` está como no exemplo a seguir:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
end
```

Confira também se há a `gem` para o Postgres (banco de dados que o Heroku usa):

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
end
```

Feitas estas alterações no seu `Gemfile`, experimente novamente um `bundle install` e em seguida o deploy.

Comment: Deixaram um recado pra você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11124

Comment: Cigano, eu já recomendaria usar Postgres em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Mesmo que o ActiveRecord abstraia o SQL, problemas podem ocorrer ao tentar usar um banco diferente daquele que foi usado no desenvolvimento, especialmente quando se fala em SQLite. Digo por experiência própria.

Comment: @brasofilo Pior... não entendi bulhufas do recado, e não conheço bem Raspberry Pi pra responder.

Comment: @Andrey Ah, sim. Também prefiro usar um banco de dados bem semelhante ao da instância de produção. Para o âmbito da resposta, eu tenho que considerar o projeto mais básico possível, por isso que a resposta tem que envolver necessariamente o SQLite.

Comment: Com relação ao recado que eu deixei: (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17305/como-subir-meu-projeto-node-js-para-o-heroku). Esse tópico ai ficou incompleto. O raspberry pi usa um aplicativo (ddclient), p/ fixar uma porta no roteador a uma endereço DDNS (dynamic DNS). Mesmo usando o heroku, imagino necessitar disso para acessar as GPIos do meu raspberry na minha rede local.